# Unable to use gpu in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I used my colab notebooks in past week,but I am still unable to use gpu in my colab notebooks.
It says "You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Colab. Learn more
If you are interested in priority access to GPUs and higher usage limits, you may want to take a look at Colab Pro." What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not explored the issue, there are many resources which has already provided a very genuine answer to this issue. One of the relevant StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126851/how-can-i-use-gpu-again-on-google-colab-after-exceeding-usage-limit) is there in which you find a good discussion trail for the same.

As far as the concern with your last question, what should I do? It's worth trying the following options:

1. Factory Reset and try again
2. Crate multiple google account and run your code
3. There are few other vendors like Kaggle who provide a similar notebook environment, give a try this as well though they also have a usage limit.
4. Switch to a standard runtime if you are not using the GPU as when standard runtime is sufficient.

Comment: My problem persist over one week and still I am unable to access gpu?

Comment: Try another alternate approach if it's applicable to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have urgent situation, the best approach is to create a new Google account and then use colab on that account.

I met same problem recently. Maybe I used Colab too much during these days.