# You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Google Collab. how to solve it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, limit

"**You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Google Collab**". this message pop up when i try to use google collab how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does Colab's Usage limit lasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349875/how-long-does-colabs-usage-limit-lasts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use GPU again on Google Colab after exceeding usage limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126851/how-can-i-use-gpu-again-on-google-colab-after-exceeding-usage-limit)